# Python "list index out of range" error in Breadth First Traversal

Tags: python, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am trying to create a BFS in python. While I am proper adjacency list but Python is showing `"list index out of range"` error, also BFS answer is not correct all the time.

Below is the python code, I have added edges, `(1, 2), (2, 3)` and `(3, 3)`

I am trying to find BFS from vertex 2,

```
from collections import defaultdict

# This class represents a directed graph using adjacency
# list representation
class Graph:

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self):

        # default dictionary to store graph
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)

    # function to add an edge to graph
    def addEdge(self,u,v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)

    # Function to print a BFS of graph
    def BFS(self, s):

        # Mark all the vertices as not visited
        visited = [False]*(len(self.graph))

        # Create a queue for BFS
        queue = []

        # Mark the source node as visited and enqueue it
        queue.append(s)
        visited[s] = True

        while queue:

            # Dequeue a vertex from queue and print it
            s = queue.pop(0)
            print s,

            # Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued
            # vertex s. If a adjacent has not been visited,
            # then mark it visited and enqueue it
            for i in self.graph[s]:

                if visited[i] == False:

                    queue.append(i)
                    visited[i] = True




# Create a graph 
g = Graph()

g.addEdge(1, 2)
g.addEdge(2, 3)
g.addEdge(3, 3)

print "Following is Breadth First Traversal (starting from vertex 2)"
g.BFS(2)
```

The error it is showing;

```
Following is Breadth First Traversal (starting from vertex 2)
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 58, in <module>
    g.BFS(2)
  File "test.py", line 42, in BFS
    if visited[i] == False:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Not sure, why it is showing out of range. I already initialised `vertex[1]`, `vertex[2]` and `vertex[3]` as False. Also, `graph[1]`, `graph[2]` and `graph[3]` is maintaining proper adjacency list.

Also, the BFS answer should be `2 3` but it is giving only `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `visited` array has length 3 therefore `visited[3]` is out of bounds.

The issue is mainly due to the fact that python lists are indexed from 0 and therefore the line `visited = [False]*(len(self.graph))` won't create an entry `visited[len(self.graph)]`.

Moreover to debug I would suggest you to print `i` and the `visited` list before the instruction that fails to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `visited = [False]*(len(self.graph))`
With this `visited = [False]*(len(self.graph)+1)`